# Oracle: apply condition over aggregated functions and not for all rows of the SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I want to calculate for an Oracle table the max value from a select statement based not on all rows returned from the query, but on a condition over a sub-set of those rows.

I'll try to explain better with an example:

```
ID | NAME | AGE | COMPANY
 1 | Alex | 28  | A
 2 | Alan | 22  | A
 3 | Bob  | 21  | B
 4 | Carl | 20  | C 
 5 | Dave | 24  | C
 6 | Eric | 26  | C
 7 | Matt | 33  | D
```

I want to obtain the max age for every company under-25 years, but I also want to count the total numbers of persons for every company.
So, I want this result:

```
COMPANY | DEPENDENTS |  MAX_UNDER_25
   A    |     2      |      22
   B    |     1      |      21
   C    |     3      |      24
   D    |     1      |    (null)
```

How can I obtain this result with a single SQL query, without joining the elaboration for the sum of records and the other elaboration for the max with condition ?

I want to avoid this select:

```
SELECT R1.COMPANY, R1.DEPENDENTS, R2.MAX_UNDER_25 FROM
(SELECT COMPANY, COUNT(*) DEPENDENTS FROM TABLE
GROUP BY COMPANY) R1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT COMPANY, MAX(AGE) MAX_UNDER_25 FROM TABLE
WHERE AGE < 25
GROUP BY COMPANY) R2
ON R1.COMPANY = R2.COMPANY;
```

It is possible to obtain that with a more simple query?

Comment: Add (7, Matt, 33, D) to the sample data, and adjust the expected result accordingly.

Comment: I have edited it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use a `case` expression when aggregating `MAX`:

```
select company, count(*), max(case when age < 25 then age end)
from table
group by company
```

Comment: So it only need to apply the case condition? I didn't know that trick... I'll try immediately and I'll check it!

Comment: @AlessandroC: What "trick"? You didn't know the 'case' expression?

Comment: @AlessandroC  [case expression](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions004.htm#SQLRF20037)

Comment: I've never used before the case expression in that way